# Wi-Fi printer works from Ethernet source, not from Wi-Fi

Tags: wireless-networking, router, printing, ethernet, printer

I have this Wi-Fi only printer. It connects to my router just fine.

I can print from a computer connected with an Ethernet cable to my router (both a Linux stationary and a Win 8 laptop).

I cannot print from an Android phone (printer not detected in the app), I cannot print from the same Win 8 laptop if on Wi-Fi instead of Ethernet.

The Wi-Fi is always the same, to the same router, on the same band, same name.

Since it works with Ethernet on the source machine, I *suspect* that the printer itself is not at fault (could it?).

What could make the connection fail (I can't even ping the printer)? Some parameter in the router?

Then again, I've had it work a couple of times, out of hundred.

Where should I look, and for what?

---

EDIT: More interesting! My router is dual band, 2.4 GHz and 5 GHz. HP's documentation states several times that the printer and the printing device must be on the same SSID. But if I use 5 GHz on my phone, and 2.4 GHz on the printer, then I get contact!

Comment: When the computer is on wifi, can you see the printer in Explorer under Network?

Comment: Try giving the printer a static IP on your network. It may be changing and so other wireless devices cannot find it. Static Printer addressing is best in a small network.

Comment: @John I keep an Ethernet-connected computer from which I can print and ping the printer, I know its IP. While being able to ping from an Ethernet computer, I can't from a Windows computer on Wi-Fi. As soon as I connect this Windows computer with Ethernet, the printer shows up and becomes pingable.

Comment: @harrymc: no, but it doesn't either while on Ethernet. As soon as I connect Ethernet on the Windows computer, the printer automatically shows up in the Printer Settings dialog, and becomes pingable.

Comment: Is perhaps your router set to separate the cable and wifi as disjoint subnets?

Comment: @harrymc Good idea, but they're all 192.168.1.x

Comment: They will be even as separated by the router. This is a router setting that hides some IPs from others.

Comment: @harrymc But Ethernet to wifi is what works. What doesn't work is both unit and printer on wifi!

Comment: I misunderstood this, sorry. Still seems like some particularity of the router.

Comment: Some more, see my edit. Choosing another SSID than the one the printer uses allows connection!